# How to downgrade Deno

Tags: javascript, deno

Using Aleph with Deno found a bug, with the incompatible versions and I need to downgrade.
How I can downgrade the deno version from `1.8.1` to `1.6.3` without uninstalling it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `deno upgrade` command with specified version for upgrade or downgrade the deno.

```sh
deno upgrade --version 1.6.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `dvm` (an alternative to node's nvm) to have various deno versions installed (for `aleph.js`). One can easily switch the version using `dvm use VERSION` command.

```
dvm use 1.8.2
```